# How to convert a Time from the PST timezone to UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to convert a Time object from the PST timezone to UTC:

```
time = "2016-08-15 11:51:27 America/Los_Angeles"
```

I am trying to use:

```
utc = Time.parse(time).utc
```

but it doesn't return the correct time. It returns:

```
# 2016-08-15 11:51:27 UTC
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
require 'tzinfo'
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/Los_Angeles')
utc_time = tz.local_to_utc(Time.parse("2016-08-15 11:51:27"))
```

which will return:

```
=> 2016-08-15 18:51:27 UTC
```